# How to convert a string to complex<float> in C++?

Tags: c++, string, complex-numbers

How do I easily convert a string containing two floats separated by a comma into a complex?

For instance:

```
string s = "123,5.3";//input
complex<float> c(123,5.3);//output/what I need
```

Is there an simpler/faster way than to split the string, read the two values and return the`complex<float>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add the parentheses and the default `operator>>` will do it for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <complex>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
        std::string s = "123,5.3";//input

        std::istringstream is('(' + s + ')');
        std::complex<float> c;
        is >> c;

        std::cout << "the number is " << c << "\n";
}
```

PS. Funny how everyone's style is slightly different, although the answers are the same.
If you are ready to handle exceptions, this can be done with boost, too:

```
    std::complex<float> c = boost::lexical_cast<std::complex<float> >('('+s+')');
```

Answer (score 1):

[The complex class has an extraction operator.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc750/html/cpp/z0274855.htm#z0275029)  You could add parentheses around the string, and then the class would read in the number for you.